Set up ingress with HA Proxy for HA K8S cluster
So i have set up an on premise HA K8s cluster with 3 control and used HA Proxy to balance the request sent to each control plane. Here is the conf file for the same.

defaults
log     global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
timeout connect 5000
timeout client  50000
timeout server  50000
errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend kubernetes-frontend
bind :6443
mode tcp
option tcplog
default_backend kubernetes-backend


backend kubernetes-backend
mode tcp
option tcp-check
balance roundrobin
server kmaster1 :6443 check fall 3 rise 2
server kmaster2 :6443 check fall 3 rise 2
server kmaster3 :6443 check fall 3 rise 2


With this the HA Setup was successful. Now I want to setup an ingress to access an app (2048 game) from outside. I want to use the same HA Proxy as the load balancer which sits in front of the ingress controller. I used the nginx ingress controller (V-3.5.0) and set up from the official website.
(https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installing-nic/installation-with-manifests/)
The manifest files for the deployment, service and ingress resource are as follows

apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
name: game-2048




apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
namespace: game-2048
name: deployment-2048
spec:
selector:
matchLabels:
app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
replicas: 5
template:
metadata:
labels:
app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
spec:
containers:
image: public.ecr.aws/l6m2t8p7/docker-2048:latest
imagePullPolicy: Always
name: app-2048
ports:
containerPort: 80





apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
namespace: game-2048
name: service-2048
spec:
ports:
port: 80
targetPort: 80
protocol: TCP
type: ClusterIP





apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
namespace: game-2048
name: ingress-2048
annotations:
ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
ingressClassName: alb
rules:
http:
paths:
path: /
pathType: Prefix
backend:
service:
name: service-2048
port:
number: 80

What changes should i make to the manifest files and HA Proxy conf so that my HA Proxy distributes the load among the control plane and also acts as the load balancer for the nginx ingress
I did some research and changed the HA Proxy conf

frontend kubernetes-frontend
bind :6443
mode tcp
option tcplog
default_backend kubernetes-backend

frontend ingress-frontend
bind :80
mode http
default_backend ingress-backend

backend kubernetes-backend
mode tcp
option tcp-check
balance roundrobin
server kmaster1 :6443 check fall 3 rise 2
server kmaster2 :6443 check fall 3 rise 2
server kmaster3 :6443 check fall 3 rise 2

backend ingress-backend
mode http
balance roundrobin
server service-2048 :80 check

But when i restart HA Proxy i get and error

ubuntu@ip-:~/kubernetes-ingress/deployments$ sudo systemctl status haproxy.service


haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-04-29 07:43:23 UTC; 48s ago
Docs: man:haproxy(1)
file:/usr/share/doc/haproxy/configuration.txt.gz
Process: 11482 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f $CONFIG -c -q $EXTRAOPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 11484 (haproxy)
Tasks: 3 (limit: 4666)
Memory: 69.7M
CPU: 149ms
CGroup: /system.slice/haproxy.service
├─11484 /usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -S /run/haproxy-master.sock
└─11486 /usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -S /run/haproxy-master.sock
Apr 29 07:43:23 ip-172-31-13-48 systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
Apr 29 07:43:23 ip-172-31-13-48 haproxy[11484]: [NOTICE]   (11484) : New worker #1 (11486) forked
Apr 29 07:43:23 ip-172-31-13-48 systemd[1]: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
Apr 29 07:43:26 ip-172-31-13-48 haproxy[11486]: [WARNING]  (11486) : Server ingress-backend/service-2048 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 timeout, check duration>
Apr 29 07:43:26 ip-172-31-13-48 haproxy[11486]: [NOTICE]   (11486) : haproxy version is 2.4.24-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
Apr 29 07:43:26 ip-172-31-13-48 haproxy[11486]: [NOTICE]   (11486) : path to executable is /usr/sbin/haproxy
Apr 29 07:43:26 ip-172-31-13-48 haproxy[11486]: [ALERT]    (11486) : backend 'ingress-backend' has no server available!

